# Php + ffmpeg объединение команд без промежуточного файла

Tags: php, ffmpeg

По отдельности команды
`shell_exec('ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -vf reverse out.mp4’)`
И
`shell_exec('ffmpeg -y -i out.mp4 -vcodec copy -vbsf h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts out.ts’)` 
Работают

Можно ли объединить их в одну без использования промежуточного out.mp4

Comment: Вы всего лишь испугались другого видеокодека по умолчанию, что ли? `ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -c:v h264 -vf reverse -vbsf h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts out.ts`

Comment: Благодарю! Очень помогли!